# spark job and hive script automation

Tags: apache-spark, hive, oozie, bigdata

I want to run a spark job and hive sql script in a sequence , one after the other. I am doing it using the shell script . Is there any other recommended way/best practice to achieve this  ? I searched on web ,does oozie fit in this scenario  ?

Comment: https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could define an Oozie workflow in order to execute first a [spark action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html) and then a [HiveQL action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/DG_HiveActionExtension.html). For instance, you could have a workflow definition like this one.

```
<workflow-app name="your_sequence" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    ...
    <start to="firstSparkJob"/>

    <action name="firstSparkJob">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>[JOB-TRACKER]</job-tracker>
            <name-node>[NAME-NODE]</name-node>
            <prepare>
               <delete path="[PATH]"/>
               ...
               <mkdir path="[PATH]"/>
               ...
            </prepare>
            <job-xml>[SPARK SETTINGS FILE]</job-xml>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>[PROPERTY-NAME]</name>
                    <value>[PROPERTY-VALUE]</value>
                </property>
                ...
            </configuration>
            <master>[SPARK MASTER URL]</master>
            <mode>[SPARK MODE]</mode>
            <name>[SPARK JOB NAME]</name>
            <class>[SPARK MAIN CLASS]</class>
            <jar>[SPARK DEPENDENCIES JAR / PYTHON FILE]</jar>
            <spark-opts>[SPARK-OPTIONS]</spark-opts>
            <arg>[ARG-VALUE]</arg>
                ...
            <arg>[ARG-VALUE]</arg>
            ...
        </spark>
        <ok to="HiveAction"/>
        <error to="ErrorSpark"/>
    </action>

    <action name="HiveAction">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>[JOB-TRACKER]</job-tracker>
            <name-node>[NAME-NODE]</name-node>
            <prepare>
               <delete path="[PATH]"/>
               ...
               <mkdir path="[PATH]"/>
               ...
            </prepare>
            <job-xml>[HIVE SETTINGS FILE]</job-xml>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>[PROPERTY-NAME]</name>
                    <value>[PROPERTY-VALUE]</value>
                </property>
                ...
            </configuration>
            <script>[HIVE-SCRIPT]</script>
            <param>[PARAM-VALUE]</param>
                ...
            <param>[PARAM-VALUE]</param>
            <file>[FILE-PATH]</file>
            ...
            <archive>[FILE-PATH]</archive>
            ...
        </hive>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="ErrorHive"/>
    </action>
    ...
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```